Resource Missing Error with Stripe's `confirmSetupIntent` in React Native
I'm using the @stripe/stripe-react-native (version 0.19.0) package in my React Native app. When I attempt to confirm a Setup Intent with the confirmSetupIntent method, I receive the following error:
{
  "stripeErrorCode": "resource_missing",
  "localizedMessage": "An unexpected error occurred. Try again in a few seconds.",
  "message": "No such setupintent: 'seti_123456789ABCDE'",
  "type": "invalid_request_error",
  "code": "Failed"
}

Here my code
const { error, setupIntent } = await confirmSetupIntent(
  stripeSetupIntent.setupIntentClientSecret,
  {
    paymentMethodType: 'Card',
    paymentMethodData: {
      billingDetails: {
        name: paymentMethodInfo.companyName,
        email: paymentMethodInfo.email,
      },
    },
  }
);

The Setup Intent ID seti_123456789ABCDE seems to be missing, but i find it on the stripe dashboard.

What could be causing this "resource missing" error?
Is there something I'm missing in the confirmSetupIntent call?


To fix it, i have to remove the stripeAccountId in the 
<StripeProvider
    publishableKey={stripeSetupIntent.stripeInitializerKey}
    // stripeAccountId={stripeSetupIntent.stripeAccountId}
>
    {MyComponent}
</StripeProvider>


That error means that the SetupIntent you are trying to confirm does not exist in the Stripe account you are using.
If you can find the SetupIntent ID in your Dashboard, then it either means:

You have multiple Stripe accounts, and you used the API key of the wrong account to make the API request.
Or you are using Stripe Connect, and you are confusing the platform account with the connected account. For example if the SetupIntent lives on the connected account, make sure to use the Stripe-Account header in the API request.


I use the same api key on the webapp (react) and it's working, how check  Stripe-Account header, when i'm calling confirmSetupIntent ?

I found, it's because i use stripeAccountId in StripeProvider, so stripe don't use the great account, connect instead of platform. thx for help
